# How to display uploaded images in vuejs from golang api using mux

Tags: go, vuejs2

I have created api using golang mux and mysql database . In response i'm getting image but not able to display image ... i have give image path but not displaying . my API response is below. My go lang api base url is http://localhost:8000/employees and image file uploading inside **project_name/images** and this uploaded image want to display in vuejs application . Please help me out i'm new in golang. Thank you

```
 {
    "ID": 23,
    "CreatedAt": "2022-02-28T11:35:40.99Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "2022-02-28T11:35:40.99Z",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "firstName": "Pankaj",
    "lastName": "Pankaj",
    "email": "pankaj@gmail.com",
    "gender": "M",
    "age": "15",
    "salary": "15000",
    "profileImage": "non-profits.0158d8ef.png"
}
```

Image url: http://localhost:8000/images/non-profits.0158d8ef.png